# Is there a "stack and map" analogue with dicts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, mapping

I recently had to map dict keys to values in an assessment question. I started with the following:

```
files=
{'Code.py': 'Stan', 'Output.txt': 'Randy', 'Input.txt': 'Randy'}
```

And was to map the files to their owners, for which I used the following:

```
mapped={
        name:[key for key,value in files.items() if value==name]
        for name in list(set([value for key,value in files.items()]))
        }
```

Which gave me what I wanted in the `mapped` dict:

```
{'Stan': ['Code.py'], 'Randy': ['Output.txt', 'Input.txt']}
```

I was just wondering if there is a more Pandas-like way of doing the same thing, but with a plain dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
mapped = defaultdict(list)
​
for k, v in files.items():
    mapped[v].append(k)

mapped
# defaultdict(list, {'Stan': ['Code.py'], 'Randy': ['Output.txt', 'Input.txt']})
```

Or use `setdefault` method on the dictionary:

```
mapped = {}
​
for k, v in files.items():
    mapped.setdefault(v, []).append(k)

mapped
# {'Stan': ['Code.py'], 'Randy': ['Output.txt', 'Input.txt']}
```

---

Or if you prefer `pandas` (which would not be as efficient for this task however):

```
s = pd.Series(files)
s.groupby(s).agg(lambda x: x.index.tolist()).to_dict()
# {'Randy': ['Input.txt', 'Output.txt'], 'Stan': ['Code.py']}
```

---

Timing on the small sample data:

```
%%timeit
from collections import defaultdict
mapped = defaultdict(list)
​
for k, v in files.items():
    mapped[v].append(k)
# 2 µs ± 33.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%%timeit
s = pd.Series(files)
s.groupby(s).agg(lambda x: x.index.tolist()).to_dict()
# 2.12 ms ± 54.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: This is a great answer. What if, as is the case in many assessments, I were unable to do any imports?

Comment: Use `setdefault` on an ordinary dictionary should work the same as `defaultdict`.

Comment: Is there some way to iterate a python3 `map` object that is more robust than using `any()`? See my answer below for the reason I ask.