# Fastest way to iterate over a Python3 map

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, iterator, mapping

I recently asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50028939/is-there-a-stack-and-map-analogue-with-dicts/50030625#50030625) question, and I modified one of the solutions, which uses a loop, to use a map instead. Of course, in Python3, `map()` returns an iterator and will not execute the callback until it is iterated over. Consider the following dictionary and mapping functions:

```
files = {'Code.py': 'Stan', 'Output.txt': 'Randy', 'Input.txt': 'Randy'}
```

is the dictionary

```
mapped = {}

for k, v in files.items():
    mapped.setdefault(v, []).append(k)
```

Runs almost twice as fast as:

```
mapped = {}

any(map(lambda i: mapped.setdefault(i[1],[]).append(i[0]),files.items()))
```

My (uneducated) guess is that building the map object and then iterating over it is just less efficient than performing the callback in a real loop. My question is: Is there a better way to use `map` that either executes the callback on build, or is there a faster way to iterate over the map than using `any`? For reference, here are the runtimes of each:

```
#timeit
#using setdefault with any, lambda, map:
#1.46 µs ± 12.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
#using setdefault with loop:
#826 ns ± 2.75 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Comment: While I agree with the Python tag being added, I'm not sure if it should be the primary tag, because Python2 `map` returns a list and not an iterator.

Comment: What's a "robust" way to iterate over something?

Comment: Would ou rather I just write "fast"?

Comment: Perhaps a good answer would be to describe the side effects of using `any` and `map` and why the loop is hands down the better option. I'll post one in a little bit if it hasn't been posted yet

Comment: `mapped.append.setdefault(v, []).append(k)`  .. .thats a typo? the `.append.` ?

Comment: Yes, I'll fix it, also I'll be answering this soon. The Gist is do not use map and any for void methods (like one appends a dictionary iteratively) because they are meant to return values and still will, which is an unwanted side effect.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is simple, thanks to @Aran-Fey for schooling me. This is not a good use case for `map` and `any`, because the loop isn't meant to return anything, rather, it is meant to modify the dictionary in place. Using `map` and `any` has the unwanted side effects of creating a map object and returning a boolean after iterating over it, neither of which are necessary. Apart from being less readable, my "one liner" produces two unwanted outputs, while the plain loop does no such thing. So on top of being only half as fast at runtime, my method also has these unwanted side effects and therefore should not be used, plain and simple.

Comment: As a side note, this was still WAY faster than using pandas